# c++ multithreading const parameter question

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm in the design phase of a multi threading problem I might implement in c++. Will be the first time implementing something multi threaded in c++. The question is quite simple: If I have a function with a const parameter as input, is it just the function under consideration that is not allowed to alter it? Or does c++ guarantee that the parameter will not change (even if another thread tries to access it mid-function)?

```
void someFunction(const SomeObject& mustNotChange){
    bool check;
    if(mustNotChange.getNumber()==0) check == true; //sleep for 10s
    if(check && mustNotChange.getNumber()!=0) //CRASH!!!
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, modification of `const` object leads to undefined behavior: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.type.cv-4.sentence-1.

Comment: Note that C++ does not guarantee that the parameter will not change. If you, for instance, pass its address elsewhere, dereference it there, then cast to non-const, and finally modify (which results in UB), C++ allows you to do that.

Comment: EDIT: indeed I forgot to mention the parameter I would like to pass by ref (now updated)

Comment: Examples where value `const X&` can change in some way: lazy evaluation, function calls a callback which is modifying variable passed by argument. But his should not lead to a crash (indicated by code comment). Please provide more details of your problem: MORE CODE.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `const` doesn't make any difference for other threads as `mustNotChange` is in your current function stack space (or even a register) which should not be accessible by other threads.

I assume you are more interested in the case where other threads can access the memory, something like:

```
void someFunction(const int& mustNotChange)
{
    //...
}

void someOtherFunction(int& mayCHange)
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::thread t0([&i](){someFunction(i);});
    std::thread t1([&i](){someOtherFunction(i);});
    
    t0.join();
    t1.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

In this case the `const` ensure that `someFunction` can't change the value of `mustNotChange` and if it does it's `undefined behavior`, but this doesn't offer any guarantees about other functions that can access the same memory.

As a conclusion:

- if you don't share data (as in the same memory location) between threads as you do in your example you don't have to worry about data races
- if you share data, but no function can change the shared data (all functions receive data as `const`) you don't have to worry about data races. Please note that in current example if you change `i` before both threads `join` it's still a data race!
- if you share data and at least one function can change the data you
  must synchronization mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to say by just looking at the code if the referred-to object can change or not. This is why it's important to [design](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-concurrency) the application with concurrency in mind, to, for example, [minimize explicit sharing of writable data](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#cp3-minimize-explicit-sharing-of-writable-data).

It doesn't matter that an object is accessed inside a function or through a `const` reference, the rules are the same. In the [C++ memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model), accessing the same (non-atomic) value concurrently is possible only for *reading*. As soon as at least one *writer* is involved (in any thread), no other reads or writes may happen concurrently.

Furthermore, reads and writes in different threads must be synchronized; this is known as the "happens-before" semantics; locking and releasing a mutex or waiting on an atomic are examples of synchronization events which "release" writes to other threads, which subsequently "acquire" those writes.

For more details on C++ concurrency there is a very good book "*C++ Concurrency in Action*". Herb Sutter also has a nice [atomic<> weapons](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2) talk.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is **yes**; You are passing the variable by **const value** and hence the function to which this variable is scoped is not allowed to alter it.

Comment: in 99% yes but there is this 1% where this is not true. Examples: lazy evaluation, callback modifying variable which was passed by argument.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to think of a const parameter in C++ as a promise by the function not to change the value. It doesn't mean someone else doesn't.